# Upgrade Wix Burn: Custom Bootstrapper Upgrade is not working

Tags: wix

I am using wixtoolset installer for creating Custom UI (Burn UI) for my installer having 10-12 Msi's. I have created the bundle for the same and created the UI which calls the install action to install the bundle and uninstall to uninstall whole bundle and everything is working fine for me.

Now issue occurs when I am trying to upgrade, I tried with UpdateReplace and UpdateReplaceEmbedded action of bootstrapper engine but installer stuck with the below error

```
[1DC8:1E70][2020-06-24T15:10:58]i200: Plan begin, 1 packages, action: UpdateReplace
[1DC8:1E70][2020-06-24T15:10:58]e000: Error 0x8000ffff: Invalid package type.
[1DC8:1E70][2020-06-24T15:10:58]e000: Error 0x8000ffff: Failed to calculate plan actions for package: (null)
[1DC8:1E70][2020-06-24T15:10:58]e000: Error 0x8000ffff: Failed to plan execute package.
[1DC8:1E70][2020-06-24T15:10:58]e000: Error 0x8000ffff: Failed to process update package.
[1DC8:1E70][2020-06-24T15:10:58]e000: Error 0x8000ffff: Failed to plan update.
[1DC8:1E70][2020-06-24T15:10:58]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x8000ffff
```

Can anyone please help with this, as I am trying to figure it out since a week but no luck

Many Thanks in advance.